# Powershell: Getting a Switch option to call functions within a set of DO loops

Tags: powershell

Problem: I'm trying to get a switch to work within a set of DO loops to provide a user interactive script that pulls data from Microsoft online. This uses all built-in functions from MSOL.

Weirdly enough, running just the switch section works fine with the output. As soon as I run this as written within the loop, the script will not provide the output until the loop starts over.

Drafting Framework Code:

```
Begin {
        
    #Connect to Microsoft Online Services
    #Connect-MsolService

    # Get All users Disambiguation only.
    $AllMSOLUsers = Get-MsolUser -All
        
    Function GatherLicenseStates {
        
        # View Licenses and amounts
        $Script:GetLicenseCount = Get-MsolAccountSku

        # Unlicensed
        $Script:Unlicensed = Get-MsolUser -All | ? { $_.isLicensed -eq $False }

        # All Licensed users sorted
        $Script:Licensed = Get-MsolUser -All | ? { $_.isLicensed -eq $True } | Sort | Select Displayname, Userprincipalname, Licenses

        # E1 Licenses
        $Script:Standard = Get-MsolUser | Where-Object { ($_.licenses).AccountSkuId -match "StandardPack" }

        # E3 Licenses
        $Script:Enterprise = Get-MsolUser | Where-Object { ($_.licenses).AccountSkuId -match "EnterprisePack" }
        
    }
    # Call Gather Licenses for initial data
    #GatherLicenseStates

    # Variables for working with this program ADD SWITCH LATER FOR OTHER SERVICES
    # Disable Planner
    $DisablePlans = "PROJECTWORKMANAGEMENT"

    Function MainMenu {
        
        $Script:MainMenu = @(
            "`n"
            "Main Menu: Please select an option. 
                `n" 
            "1) See Licenses" 
            "2) Breakdown All Licensed Users"
            "3) End Program" 
            "`n"
        )
        $MainMenu
    }


    Function Licensed {
        
        $Script:LicensedMenu = @(
           
            "`n"
            "Licensed Menu: Please Select an option"
            "`n"
            "1) Show all Licensed users"
            "2) Show all Unlicensed users"
            "3) Show all E3 users"
            "4) Show all E1 users"
            "5) Go to Main Menu"          

        ) 
        $LicensedMenu
    }

}

# Start Manipulation phase. Working with the data and re-requesting, if needed, from the Begin phase
Process {

    # Call Gather Licenses for initial data
    GatherLicenseStates

    Do {
        Do {
            $End = $null
            MainMenu 
            $Choice = (Read-host "Selection")
            Switch ($choice) {
        
                1 {
                    Write-output `n"Calling get licenses!"`n;
                    $Script:GetLicenseCount | Write-output;
                    # pause
                }
                2 {
                    Do {
                        Do {
                                    
                            Licensed
                            Switch ($LicensedChoice) {

                                1 { $Licensed }
                                2 { $Unlicensed }
                                3 { $Enterprise }
                                4 { $Standard }
                                5 { $GoToMainMenu = "Go" }
                            }
                        }Until($LicensedChoice -eq "1" -or $LicensedChoice -eq "2" -or $LicensedChoice -eq "3" -or $LicensedChoice -eq "4" -or $LicensedChoice -eq "5")
                    }Until($GoToMainMenu -eq "Go")

                }
                3 { $Script:End = "End" }

            }

        }Until($choice -eq "1" -or $Choice -eq "2" -or $Choice -eq "3")
    }Until($End -eq "End")
}
```

Running the Switch works fine for outputting the results. Putting this within a set of DO loops breaks the functionality.

Switch only code and output:

Code:

```
$Choice = (Read-host "Selection")

Switch ($choice) {        
    1 {
        Write-output `n"Calling get licenses!"`n;
        $GetLicenseCount | Write-output;
        # pause
    }
    2 {
        Do {
            Do {
                                    
                Licensed
                Switch ($LicensedChoice) {

                    1 { $Licensed }
                    2 { $Unlicensed }
                    3 { $Enterprise }
                    4 { $Standard }
                    5 { $GoToMainMenu = "Go" }
                }
            }Until($LicensedChoice -eq "1" -or $LicensedChoice -eq "2" -or $LicensedChoice -eq "3" -or $LicensedChoice -eq "4" -or $LicensedChoice -eq "5")
        }Until($GoToMainMenu -eq "Go")

    }
    3 { $Script:End = "End" }
}
```

Switch only output:

```
Selection: 1

Calling get licenses!


AccountSkuId                  ActiveUnits WarningUnits ConsumedUnits
------------                  ----------- ------------ -------------
Company:STREAM             1000000     0            0           
Company:ENTERPRISEPACK     1000        0            0         
Company:FLOW_FREE          10000       0            0          
Company:SPB                1000        0            0            
Company:POWERAPPS_VIRAL    10000       0            0            
Company:EXCHANGESTANDARD   1000        0            0           
Company:AAD_PREMIUM_P2     1000        0            0            
Company:POWER_BI_STANDARD  1000000     0            0            
Company:TEAMS_EXPLORATORY  3000        0            0            
Company:EXCHANGEENTERPRISE 1000        0            0            
Company:STANDARDPACK       1000        0            0
```

Do Loop Code Output:

```
Main Menu: Please select an option. 
                

1) See Licenses
2) Breakdown All Licensed Users
3) End Program


Selection: 1

Calling get licenses!


Selection: 

---------------------
Within the Do Loops it seems to ask for the selection again at the top of the loop before providing option 1's output of licenses. 

Ideal output:

selection: 1

AccountSkuId                  ActiveUnits WarningUnits ConsumedUnits
------------                  ----------- ------------ -------------
Company:STREAM             1000000     0            0           
Company:ENTERPRISEPACK     1000        0            0         
Company:FLOW_FREE          10000       0            0          
Company:SPB                1000        0            0            
Company:POWERAPPS_VIRAL    10000       0            0            
Company:EXCHANGESTANDARD   1000        0            0           
Company:AAD_PREMIUM_P2     1000        0            0            
Company:POWER_BI_STANDARD  1000000     0            0            
Company:TEAMS_EXPLORATORY  3000        0            0            
Company:EXCHANGEENTERPRISE 1000        0            0            
Company:STANDARDPACK       1000        0            0    


Main Menu: Please select an option. 
                

1) See Licenses
2) Breakdown All Licensed Users
3) End Program


selection: <--- Pending next selection
```

Absolutely banging my head on the wall trying to figure out why this simple code is not performing as imagined. I'm missing something equally simple I'm sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Replace `| Write-Output` with `| Out-Host`

Comment: Absolutely worked! Tried a million ways before asking but should have saved the time! Thank you very much for the answer and Re-formatting!